# How does Spring Security sessions work?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, spring-security

How do Spring sessions work when you login to a form on Spring security as described in this tutorial? http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/tutorial.html

Is it cookie based? Im not sure what exactly is going on that allows the user to log in and have it remember and keep you logged in for the remainder of the browsing session.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is cookie based similar to how the servlet maintains sessions . If cookies are disabled, you would have to resort to URL rewriting .According to the FAQ [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/faq.html#faq-concurrent-session-same-browser).

"All it sees are HTTP requests and it ties those to a particular session according to the value of the the JSESSIONID cookie that they contain. When a user authenticates during a session, Spring Security's concurrent session control checks the number of other authenticated sessions that they have. If they are already authenticated with the same session, then re-authenticating will have no effect. "

also

"If clients have cookies disabled, and you are not rewriting URLs to include the jsessionid, then the session will be lost. Note that the use of cookies is preferred for security reasons, as it does not expose the session information in the URL. "

See [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/remember-me.html) for the Single sign on feature

Comment: How does this differ from Remember-Me?

Comment: If I am not wrong , Session is tracked using the JSESSIONID cookie while the Remember me cookie is a different one and goes by the name 'SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE' .The info contained in this for 'Remember me' use .